# echo out JOIN query PHP in dynamic menu

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables inside a test db:
information (id, menu, position, visible)
pages (id, information_id, menu, position, visible, content)

with which I try to make a related navigation like so:

> - public (inside table information with id = 1)
>
>   - home (inside table pages with information_id = 1)
>   - about us (inside table pages with information_id = 1)
>   - work (inside table pages with information_id = 1)
> - cms (inside table information with id = 2)
>
>   - articles (inside table pages with information_id = 2)
>   - add users (inside table pages with information_id = 2)

when I query the tables in PHPMyadmin I get the result I need, but when I try to echo the result out in PHP, I don't get the wanted structured menu with subitems.

```
<?php

$info_set = $db->prepare("SELECT *
                          FROM ccms.information");
$info_set->execute();

while ($information = $info_set->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<li>" . $information["menu"] . "</li>";

    $page_set = $db->prepare("SELECT i.*,p.*  
                              FROM information i 
                              JOIN pages p 
                              ON i.id = p.information_id");

    $page_set->execute();
    echo "<ul>";

    while ($pages = $page_set->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<li>" . $pages["menu"] . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

The result is that the menu items from information table get echo`ed out fine, but the subitems aren't.
What Am I missing here?

I apologize to everyone offended by the perhaps simplistic nature of my question, I am a novice to PHP & SQL.

Comment: Do you need the `ccms.` in front of your table names in the subitem query?

Comment: Your subitem query can probably be more efficiently written as `SELECT * FROM pages p where p.information_id = :iid` followed by `$page_set->bindParam(':iid', $information['id']);`

Comment: Thank you Nick, that works. Could/ would you explain to me what the bindParam does? I would like to understand.

Comment: Basically it links the value (in this case `$information['id']`) to the named parameter (`:iid`) in the query that has been prepared. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) has a good explanation.

Comment: thank you very much Nick! this helps a lot.